# Convert an ip address to its decimal equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, ip

I would like to write a method but have no idea where to start concerning converting a String to decimal format.

Here's an example of what I would like:

I have the following string:

`String ipAddress = "192.168.1.10 "`

And I want to convert it to its decimal equivalent:

`3232235786`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about (tested & working):

```
    String ipAddress = "192.168.1.10";
    String[] addrArray = addr.split("\\.");

    long ipDecimal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < addrArray.length; i++) {

        int power = 3 - i;
        ipDecimal += ((Integer.parseInt(addrArray[i]) % 256 * Math.pow(256, power)));
    }

    System.out.println(ipDecimal);
```

Comment: i think its because you and the other guy both took the code from the same source , so people think one of you copied it from the other when in reality you both found it somewhere else

Comment: Yes I copied it from somewhere else but I made sure it worked b4 posting.

Comment: @BobSinclar People can just look at the "answer time" and see that Reimeus was first.

Comment: true though 5 minutes isnt alot, when posting from a phone that time isnt that significant.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
new BigInteger( InetAddress.getByName("1.1.1.1").getAddress() ).intValue()
```

If I remember correctly this should do the trick... obviously use your IP rather than 1.1.1.1.

Comment: This doesn't work for large decimal values of the ip (eg: 190.19.14.163) (too big for an `int`)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String ip="192.168.1.10";
        String[] addrArray = ip.split("\\.");
        long num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < addrArray.length; i++)
        {
            int power = 3 - i;
            num += ((Integer.parseInt(addrArray[i]) % 256 * Math.pow(256, power)));
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3232235786
```

Comment: Did you just copy that answer from `Reimeus`?

Comment: It's mentioned [here](http://nscraps.com/Java/1353-convert-ip-address-integer-number.htm). I have just tested and answered as it worked fine.

Comment: But **perhaps** not after testing.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of convertion :

```
A.B.C.D = D + (C * 256) + (B * 256 * 256) + (A * 256 * 256 * 256)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to binary then convert that to decimal

or try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Comment: if he is having trouble with it i guess i could write the code for it, its not that complicated. Oh well..

Comment: Yeah, I just added the code to do it in my post.  It only works with ints, but I'm pretty sure all you'd have to change for it to apply to this would be to replace every instance of "int" with "long."

Answer (score 0):

Convert each segment to an 8-bit binary number, concatenate all 4 8-bit binary numbers into one 32-bit binary number, then convert than 32-bit binary number to decimal and you have your answer.

EDIT: Here's how you can convert numbers to and from binary:

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String bin) {
    int result = 0;
    int len = bin.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result += Integer.parseInt(bin.charAt(i) +  "") * Math.pow(2, len - i - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

public static String decimalToBinary(int num) {
    String result = "";
    while(true) {
        result += num % 2;
        if(num < 2)
            break;
        num = num / 2;
    }
    result = reverse(result);
    return result;
}

public static String reverse(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        result += str.charAt(i);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for translating an IP to an Integer in order to use IP2Country-Databases by [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/country) or [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db1-ip-country).

You can copy paste this code into a helper class for your own needs.

```
public static int ip2Int(String ip) {
    int ipInt = 0;
    String[] tokens = ip.split("\\.");
    int factor = 256*256*256;
    for (String t:tokens) {
        ipInt += new Integer(t).intValue()*factor;
        factor = factor/256;
    }
    return ipInt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string represented IP address (doesn't matter if IPv4 or IPv6) to decimal by converting it to BigInteger:

```
private static BigInteger ipToDecimal(String ip) {
    return new BigInteger(1, InetAddresses.forString(ip).getAddress());
}
```

And when necessary then you can convert it back by:

```
private static String decimalToIp(String decimal) throws Exception {
    BigInteger parsed = new BigInteger(decimal);

    if (parsed.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(4294967295L)) > 0) {
        return Joiner.on(":").join(Splitter.fixedLength(4).split(parsed.toString(16)));
    } else {
        return InetAddress.getByName(decimal).getHostAddress();
    }
}
```

Converting back is not perfect - you must count with IPv4 mapped addresses [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses)